# How to center align a group floating buttons in vuetify?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

This is my code:

```html
<v-container height="0">
    
  <v-row align="center" justify="center">
    <v-hover v-slot:default="{ hover }" v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index">
      <v-tooltip top color="transparent">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
          <v-btn
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
            color="white"
            fab
            dark
            medium
            absolute
            bottom
            left
            @click="OptionSelected(option)"
            :style="{ marginBottom: '120px', marginLeft: 10 + 65*(index) + 'px', marginRight: 10 + 65*(index) + 'px'}"
          >
            <v-img
              height="55"
              width="40"
              style="object-fit: contain; border-radius: 50%"
              :src="option.thumbnail"
            >
            </v-img>
            <v-expand-transition>
              <div
                v-if="hover || option.selected"
                class="d-flex amber v-card--reveal body-1"
                style="border-radius: 50%;"
              >
              </div>
            </v-expand-transition>
          </v-btn> 
        </template>
        <div style="margin-bottom: 100px; background-color: white; color: black; padding: 10px; border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 5px">
          {{ option.title }}
        </div>
      </v-tooltip>
    </v-hover>
  </v-row>
  .......
  </v-container>
```

I have a group of floating buttons which I am trying to center align horizontally. I tried `style="left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)"`. But the buttons did not center align. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

This is my updated code. There are tooltips and hover elements also in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `<v-btn>`s inside a [`<v-row>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-row), with its `justify` and `align` props set to `center`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.3.15/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.3.15/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<v-app id="app">
  <v-container class="grey lighten-5 mb-6" >
    <v-row align="center" justify="center">
      <v-btn
             fab
             dark
             medium
             v-for="index in 3"
             >
        {{index}}
      </v-btn>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</v-app>
```